# Display data in laravel using one to many relationship

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to display data using laravel. I currently want to display reviews of the hotels on my system. Prior to modifications of code my posts were showing, however with the following code, no posts show at all and i am struggling as to why this is happening.

**PostsController.php**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $review = Post::find(1)->reviews()->where('title', 'posts_title')->get();

    return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'review'));
}
```

**Post.php**

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review', 'title', 'post_title');
}
```

**Review.php**

```
public function post()
{    
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

the variable `title` is the title of the review. `post_title` is the title of the hotel. Both titles should match (in my system they do). I know you would use ID's but i think that is difficult in my situation

I want to display the review that matches the right hotel. Bare in mind previously, all my hotels were displaying, however after changing the code it does not display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting no `Review`s in your query is this line:

```
$review = Post::find(1)->reviews()->where('title', 'posts_title')->get();
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When you use a `where()` clause the first parameter is the column name to query against and the second parameter is the actual value to compare.. not a column name. So this will try to find every review that has a title with a value `"posts_title"` (literally)... hence you have 0 records returned.

Now, you also need to know how relationships work. If you define a relationship in your `Post` model like the following:

```
# Post.php

public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review', 'title', 'post_title');
}
```

This will work as follows: It'll get all the reviews that has the `reviews.title` column equals to `posts.post_title` column.

So, if this setup is correct for your dabatase, you won't need to re-state this condition, just execute the query and call the relationship method instead:

```
# PostsController.php

$related_reviews = Post::find(1)->reviews;
```

Also notice that, in need of use the reverse relationship, you'll need to also tell laravel the custom PK/FK to use in order to get the correct results.

```
# Review.php

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'title', 'post_title');
}
```

---

As a side note, if you manage your hotels as `posts` in your database.. a proper name for this model and table should be `Hotel` and `hotels`, respectively.

Comment: can you explain the postcontroller.php code better. Do i still keep : public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        //$review = Review::all();
        $review = Post::find(1)->reviews()->where('title',  'posts_title')->get();

        return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'review'));
      
        
    } the same code but include that new piece.

Comment: also unsure on what related_reviews means. I am quite new to laravel

Comment: @cutesengh the $related_reviews variable just gets the `reviews` linked with that specific `post`. The code that you've posted in the comment isn't in your original question, so I don't know what are you trying to achieve with that exactly. Do you want to get the Post and also the related reviews? Just do this: `$post = Post::find(1)->load('reviews')`

Comment: Exactly, i want to obtain all the related reviews for the post. I will try that now see what i can get, thanks. i currently have the post but no reviews. I want to obtain all the relevant reviews of that post.

Comment: I recieve the error: compact(): Undefined variable: review                                                                 the code i am implementing is:                                                                                                                                              public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        //$review = Review::all();
        
        //$review = Post::find(1)->reviews;
        $post = Post::find(1)->load('reviews');
        return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'review'));

Comment: $review = Review::all(); displays all my posts but not the specific posts that match the hotel i want

Comment: @cutesengh sorry for the delay. When you do this: `$post = Post::with('reviews')->find(1);` you are already retrieving the related reviews. You'll see an additional attribute in your `$post` object called.. you guessed it: `reviews`, this will hold a collection of all the related reviews for that particular post (id=1).